# How to auto-fit a wpf window to a ListBox content?

Tags: c#, wpf

Why does this WPF window does not auto-sets its width and height, depending of the Grid or listbox size (so depending of the number of items into the listbox)?:

```
<controls:MetroWindow x:Class="....."
                 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                      xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"  
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
                        Width="Auto" Height="Auto" MaxHeight="500" MaxWidth="500">

<Grid  Background="Gray" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" >   
    <ListBox   Width="Auto" Height="Auto" FontSize="12" FontWeight="SemiBold" ItemsSource="{Binding ListError}"  >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
 </Grid>
</controls:MetroWindow>
```

In this case, it renders 500*500 ( = my MaxWidth and MaxHeight values).
If I remove the MaxWidth and MaxHeight values, it till does not auto-fit to the listbox size.

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `Height` and `Width` properties, and add the following :

```
SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
```

Comment: Thx a ton  Xiaoy312 :)